# bootstrap tabs stops working after working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a bootstrap tabs to create a timeline like tabs. It works only first 4 times and then stops changing after that.
I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jypqyd3j/1/) please look into it.

code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="timeline">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><li role="presentation"><a href="#2011" aria-controls="2011" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2011</a></li></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><li role="presentation"><a href="#2013" aria-controls="2013" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2013</a></li></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><li role="presentation"><a href="#2014" aria-controls="2014" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2014</a></li></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><li role="presentation"><a href="#2016" aria-controls="2016" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2016</a></li></div>
  </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="2011">
        <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="2013">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="2014">
    <p>
    3</p>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="2016">
    <p>
        4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
$('#timeline a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you close off your code statements with a semi colon ;

Also needed to remove the active class for the tabs li.
Web dev tools are your friend. watch for classes which may be added

```
$('#timeline a').click(function (e) {
  $('#timeline li').removeClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5253gmpu/

Comment: Js statements don't need semicolon.

Comment: thank you, after seeing your example i feel stupid :P
btw: fiddle is missing the `removeClass`

Comment: Haha yeah true, just good practice. I was always taught its best to just add them.

Comment: @Enkhtuvshin Oh sorry im new to both stack overflow and jsfiddle, not sure how the fork works exactly in jsfiddle :/ guess I better read up on it.
Glad I could help, it's usually something simple it still gets me too. Gotta love Stack

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that the clicks stop working after the fourth click? I am having the same problem and trying to find a solution. Very strange!